# Add value to a cell in a different column based on current cell in loop google scripts

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a spreadsheet of serial numbers that I am sending via API and all I am reading is the response code, if the response code is 200 I want to add TRUE (or check mark) in the same row as the serial number but 5 or so columns to the right.

I have the following code but I am stuck on the if statement, I am having trouble referencing the current working cell.

```
function myFunction() {
var AccessToken = 'accesstokeninfohere';

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
var rangeData = sheet.getDataRange();
var lastColumn = rangeData.getLastColumn();
var lastRow = rangeData.getLastRow();

var searchRange = sheet.getRange(4,6, lastRow, 1);
var rangeValues = searchRange.getValues();

    for ( j = 0 ; j < lastRow - 1; j++){
      var SerialNumber = rangeValues[j]


  var uri = 'apiinfourl' + SerialNumber;
  var params = {
    'method': 'GET',
    'muteHttpExceptions': true,
    'headers': {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + AccessToken
    }
  };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(uri, params);
  var data = response.getContentText();
  var json = JSON.parse(data);
  var responsecode = response.getResponseCode();


  if (responsecode == "200"){
    
    ///ADD TRUE TO THE SAME ROW 5 COLUMNS TO THE RIGHT.

      };

      };
    }
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand imagine your question from `I have a spreadsheet of serial numbers that I am sending via API and all I am reading is the response code, if the response code is 200 I want to add TRUE (or check mark) in the same row as the serial number but 5 or so columns to the right.`. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect?

Comment: I have a spreadsheet with data in certain cells, I have a loop that reads the data (in this case it is a serial number of a certain device) from the spreadsheet and does a GET API call to check if that data exisits on the platform I am calling to, if the data exists I get a response code 200 back. All this works fine, where I am stuck is I want to do an if statement to check if response code = 200 insert TRUE in the same row as the data but 5 or so columns to the right.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, from your reply, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Add another variable called *row_incr* with value `4` - which is the start row - according to this line: `var searchRange = sheet.getRange(4,6, lastRow, 1);`.
- In your loop, set the value as follows:

```
if (responsecode == "200") {
    /** Set the value in the row, at the 11th column - i.e 5 columns to the right: */
    sheet.getRange("K" + row_incr).setValue("YES"); // 6th column "G" - 11th column "K".
}
/** Increment the variable. */
row_incr++;
```

***NOTE**: Depending to the data you're looping*, I would instead use a batch approach.

Answer (score 0):

- "searchrange" = `getRange(4,6, lastRow, 1);`; so the start row = 4
- The `for` loop "j" starts at 0 (zero).

  - So j=0 is a reference to the start row; and the start row = row#4.
- So, the row number for any given Serial Number = (j+4).

Comment: Right, so when I do:     sheet.getRange(j+4).setValue("TRUE"); inside the if statement I get Exception: Range not found error.

Comment: `getRange(row,column)` requires a column number too; you've just got a row value.